# Raster Calculator

Tags: raster, raster-calculator

I have a slope dataset.  How do I calculate the real surface area for this slope dataset using the raster calculator.  This is the example I was given:

orthogonal area of a raster cell in square meters over cos([slope raster] * 3.1415/180)

How do I know what the orthogonal area of the raster cell in square meter is?  Where do I check for this?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Comment: I think what you're after is the cell size of the raster. The area of the cell (flat) is Cell Width x Cell Height, how you find these out is dependent on your software... depending on your software there may already be surface area calculations.

Comment: I am using ArcInfo 10.2.  You are right Michael, I am after the cell size of the raster.  Many Thanks for your help